# Window and system tray icon does not appear when referenced from resources

Tags: python, resources, python-3.x, pyqt

This is testTray.py

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import imgAgent_rc

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)

        icon = QIcon(':/images/logo/image_16x16.png')     # Problem
        #icon = QIcon('images/logo/image_16x16.png')        # OK

        self.trayIcon.setIcon(icon)
        self.trayIcon.setVisible(True)
        self.trayIcon.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the directory structure:

```
imgAgent.qrc
imgAgent_rc.py
testTray.py
+images
|---+logo
    |---image_16x16.png
```

imgAgent.prc

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="logo">
    <file>images/logo/image_16x16.png</file>
    ...
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I generated the .py resource file using:
`pyrcc4.exe -py3 -o imgAgent_rc.py imgAgent.qrc`

The System tray icon AND the window icon do not appear when referenced from the resource, but appear normally when referenced by the relative path.
[image: Problem]  [image: OK]

Comment: could you post imgAgent.qrc, because i think the path you set for the icon in qrc file is different than /images/logo/image_16x16.png.

Comment: Yes,sorry, i forgot the most important thing. I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this resource file code:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource>
    <file>images/logo/image_16x16.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to post my .qrc file. The image is there.

Comment: You are right. I accidentally used prefix="logo". I tried icon = QIcon(':/logo/images/logo/image_16x16.png') and worked. My mistake and in front of my eyes :-P